# MaxClient (httpd), maxThreads (tomcat) and acceptCount (tomcat)

Tags: tomcat, apache2, apache, httpd.conf, mod-jk

In my project, I do have 2 web servers (httpd) and two application servers (tomcat).
Each httpd and tomcat is on separate machine.
The DNS (hardware) EQUALLY loadbalance the request to two web servers and If any httpd is down, all the requests goes to alive httpd.
Each web server can forward the request to any of the tomcats. The mod jk connector with httpd EQUALLY distributes the load between two tomcats. If one tomcat is down all the requests goes to alive tomcat.

My problem is related with the tuning of apache parameters. 
On both the tomcat, I do set **acceptCount 100** and **maxThreads 260**. and on each httpd the value for **MaxClient** is **360** (260+100). 
Please let me know if mentioned values for these parameters look feasible to you. Or any better things i can do ?

Many Thanks in advance. Please let me know, if need more info.